# Swing - Key Problems (Arrow Keys, Tab, etc.) in GUIs with TextComponents

Tags: java, swing, keyevent

I want to bind the arrow keys to some specific actions for the whole window (no matter which component is focused). In particular I want to move the selection bar in a JList with the arrow keys. My window contains a JTextArea and different JScrollPanes.

I guess that following problem occurs: When I change the list selection the textarea gains focus (which lies withing the logic which I want to realize). When the JTextArea or the JScrollPane have focus all arrow-up, etc. key events 'get lost' (or rather only affect the TextComponent/Pane).

Here is a little example which demonstrates the problem:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class KeyProblemExample extends JFrame implements ListSelectionListener {

private JList<Integer> list;
private JTextArea textArea;
private JLabel label;

public KeyProblemExample() 
{
    Font font = new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 20);
    Integer[] listValues = {1, 2, 3};
    list = new JList<>(listValues);
    list.setFixedCellWidth(50);
    list.setFont(font);
    textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    String text = Stream.generate(()-> "xyz").limit(300).collect(Collectors.joining());
    textArea.setText(text);
    textArea.setFont(font);
    label = new JLabel("bla bla bla");
    label.setFont(font);
}


private void buildLogic() 
{
    //list selection listener
    list.addListSelectionListener(this);
    //up and down keys
    AbstractAction down = new AbstractAction() {    
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (list.getSelectedIndex() >= 0 && list.getSelectedIndex() < list.getModel().getSize() - 1)
                list.setSelectedIndex(list.getSelectedIndex() + 1);
        }
    };
    AbstractAction up = new AbstractAction() {  
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (list.getSelectedIndex() >= 1 && list.getSelectedIndex() < list.getModel().getSize())
                list.setSelectedIndex(list.getSelectedIndex() - 1);
        }
    };
    KeyStroke keyDown = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, KeyEvent.ALT_MASK);
    label.getActionMap().put("indexDown", down);
    label.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(keyDown, "indexDown"); 
    KeyStroke keyUp = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0);
    label.getActionMap().put("indexUp", up);
    label.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(keyUp, "indexUp");
}


private void displayGUI() 
{
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JScrollPane sp1 = new JScrollPane();
    sp1.setViewportView(textArea);
    sp1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    sp1.setWheelScrollingEnabled(true);
    JScrollPane sp2 = new JScrollPane();
    sp2.setViewportView(list);
    sp2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    sp2.setWheelScrollingEnabled(true);
    panel.add(sp1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.add(sp2, BorderLayout.EAST);
    panel.add(label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    this.getContentPane().add(panel);      
    this.pack();
    this.setSize(400,400);
    this.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    this.setVisible(true);
}


@Override
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    textArea.requestFocus();
//  label.requestFocus();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            KeyProblemExample x = new KeyProblemExample();
            x.buildLogic();
            x.displayGUI();
        }
    };
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
}

}
```

In this example the Alt-ArrowDown command works, whereas the plain ArrowUp doesn't work. If I change the `requestFocus()` line, so that the label requests focus, ArrowUp also works (since now the label and not the textarea gains focus).

My question: What can I do to bind keys like arrow-keys, etc., 'window-wide' to specific actions (especially if I have text components in my window).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key bindings for the text components take precedence when they have focus. So you need to remove the binding from the text components with code like:

```
textComponent.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"), "none");
```

See the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make/Remove Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html#howto) for more information.

Comment: Well, whatever component has the binding you need to remove it. You can check out [Key Bindings](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/). It will show you the bindings for each component. I would guess the scrollbar has the binding.

Answer (score 0):

thank you @ camickr, the problem could be solved by your hints.

... anyway here are some further informations / solutions:

1. Disable key-actions for a whole component type (like described in camickr's [link](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/)):

   ```
   InputMap textAreaInputMap = (InputMap)UIManager.get("TextArea.focusInputMap");
   InputMap scrollPaneInputMap = (InputMap)UIManager.get("ScrollPane.ancestorInputMap");
   textAreaInputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"), "none");
   textAreaInputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN"), "none");
   scrollPaneInputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"), "none");
   scrollPaneInputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN"), "none");
   ```

   This disables up-arrow and down-arrow key inputs for all `TextArea` and `ScrollPane` components (one object of each type has to be instantiated before calling this commands)
2. Disable keys for the whole window via `KeyEventDispatcher`:

   ```
   KeyboardFocusManager manager = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
   manager.addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {
       @Override
       public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
           if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED) {
               int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
               if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                   //doAction
                   return true;
               }
               else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                   //doAction
                   return true;
               }   
           }
           return false;
       }
   });
   ```

   This executes the 'doAction' command for up-arrow respectively down-arrow key pressed 'window-wide'. Since the method returns true in both cases the key-event will not be dispatched to other components, so this keys get disabled for the textarea and the scrollpane in the example.